# Perl Text::CSV unknown variable

Tags: perl, csv

Here is an easy one.

I checked the documents. What is that in line 18? What kind of variable is `@$row`? Is it the (default output) `$_` of the
[`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV)
`getline` function ?

```
#!/efs/dist/perl5/core/5.10/exec/bin/perl

use Text::CSV;
use Time::Local ;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "$ARGV[0]";

open my $fh, "<", $file or die "$file: $!" ;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( {
    binary    => 1,
    auto_diag => 1,
} );

while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) {
    print "@$row\n" ;                  # Line 18
}
```

Comment: `$row` is an array reference. You assigned it to the return value of the `getline` method on the previous line.

Comment: How do you imagine that `@$row` might be the same variable as `$_`? Also, `getline` has no *"default output"*. I think you need to *"check the documents"* properly.

Comment: Glad to see you are feeling better Borodin.  Getline does not have a default output operator, like an array has $_. Got it.

Comment: I was attempting to use an analogy to describe my question. Getline is to @$row as  array is to $_. Getline does not have a default operator, @$row is a reference. Got it. Glad to see you are back to your old self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row` is an array reference. Try out `ref()` : http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html.